# Computer not booting after trying to install graphics drivers

Tags: boot, drivers, graphics, freeze, davinci-resolve

I bought new laptop ASUS Vivobook 14 OLED (X1405). Installed Ubuntu 22.04. First problem that I met, is that once a day computer freezes and I have to restart it via holding turn off button. Then I installed Davinci Resolve 18 and get error. Something about GPU problem. I tried to google the solution. Thought that it could be driver issues. Proceed with this instruction https://dgpu-docs.intel.com/installation-guides/ubuntu/ubuntu-jammy-arc.html . After this my computer freezes again. But when I tried to turn it on it just stops on black screen with "-" in the left corner. Except this two problems(witch i consider major) I love using Ubuntu. But I'm desperate right now. I can't find solutions both for Davinci and freezes. And considering to switch back to windows. May be some one can help me...

Comment: "get error. Something about GPU problem" is not sufficient. Please edit your question to show the exact command you entered and the exact output that was emitted.

Comment: Thank you for answering. It just show window with this message "Unsupported GPU Processing Mode please review the GPU drivers and GPU configuration under preferences" and two buttons "quit" and "update configuration". I can't give any real additional information because computer doesn't turn on. From here, I can't be sure. But I think, that I choose "update configuration", and in settings the menu about GPU, where you supposed to choose device, was empty. Also may be you have some ideas, why new laptop can freezes, without any special activities from the user?

Comment: It really sounds like the software cannot run on your device. At least in the current state of its video drivers. What kind of video card does it have, and what video drivers are you using?